# Postman 400 bad request при запуске коллекции в приложении на Windows 10

Tags: api, post, get, test-automation, postman

коллеги!

Приступила к изучению Постмана и вот столкнулась с такой проблемкой. У меня есть коллекция из 15 разных запросов- get, post, put, delete. При запуске коллекции в приложении на компе через кнопочку Run collection, 2 запроса постоянно дают ошибку. В первом случае ошибка AssertionError: expected response to have status code 200 but got 400, и видимо из-за того что не проходит этот запрос, еще 1 запрос тоже дает ошибку - AssertionError: expected response to have status code 404 but got 400. Самое интересное, что если запускать запросы по одиночке, то ошибки нет. Также я попробовала запустить всю коллекцию в Постмане, но через браузер, а не через приложение, и там все работает прекрасно. Версия приложения у меня 10.16.0. Ниже даю 1 скриншот, если нужно что-то конкреное, без проблем сделаю еще нужных скринов. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться!
[image: 400. That’s an error. Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.That’s all we know.]

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит потому, что ты перед запуском не сохраняешь свои запросы, т.е ты их написала, но не нажала в каждом из них кнопку Save в правом верхнгем углу, как итог, их кэша они запускаются норм, а если запрустить колекцию, и внимательно прочитать ошибку, то можно увидеть, что запросы то пустые!